# Why did the Latin word marmor became French marbre (which is in present day English marble)?

Tags: english, etymology, latin, french

I would like to know what process suffered the Latin word **marmor** when it was borrowed in French and became **marbre**. I know that the process from French **marbre** to English **marble** is dissimilation, i.e. change from r to l, but I don't really know how to explain the change of the ending **-BRE** in Latin for **-MOR** in French.

Comment: _Marmorem_ to _marb(o)rem_ is also dissimilation: m_m becomes m_b to be less similar.

Comment: It's not *-mor* to *-bre*, but *-more(m)* to *-bre*, because most Romance words come from the accusative.

Comment: Latin /r/ and /l/ dissimilate in  many words. Consider _colonel/coronel, marmor/marble,_ and [the Latin adjectival suffix _-al/-ar_,](https://websites.umich.edu/~jlawler/Latin_dissimilation.pdf)

Comment: _-more_ -> _-mre_ (by syncope) -> _-mbre_ (by epenthesis). Compare English _thimble_ <- OE  þȳmel.